# Input file multiple pegando apenas 1 imagem da galeria

Tags: apache-cordova, webview, galeria, android-webview

Eu tenho um app webview em cordova. No meu site ele abre normal o input file multiple, já no app, ele abre e consegue selecionar apenas 1 imagem. Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Adiciona seu código que pega as imagens na pegunta.

Comment: Brother, nada mais é quem um <input file multiple> do html.